# Android studio - custom 'Remove unused resources'

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to remove unused string resources.

In android studio, there is an option to remove unused resources. My issue is that I have a separate file that contains strings keys. At runtime I'm parsing this file and then fetching strings based on these keys. When running the remove unused resources option in android studio it can't detect that these keys are being used because they aren't referenced from code or xml.

Is it possible to somehow setup a rule in android studio to take in consideration this custom file I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a script that parses the custom file and creates an enum that holds a reference to the strings that should be kept. Generated enum looks like this.

```
enum class StringsToKeep(@StringRes stringRes: Int) {
    STRING_KEY(R.string.string_key),
    STRING_KEY_TWO(R.string.string_two),
}
```